# How to specify anchor styles in {forest} trees?

Tags: forest

I'm using {forest} to make a simple tree and I want the edges for all nodes to be filled arrows (southward directed) of a larger than normal size (so that the image I'm creating resizes well when shrunken down). I've gotten as far as specifying the arrows, but am stuck... How do I transform the itty bitty arrows into nice big filled arrows?

```
\begin{forest} 
for tree={edge=->}
[{\textbf{Footbridge Dilemma}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
  [{\textbf{Push \\Man}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
     [{\textbf{Man \\Dies}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
       [{\textbf{Workmen \\Saved}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered]
     ]
  ]
  [{\textbf{Don't Push}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
     [{\textbf{Man \\Lives}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
       [{\textbf{Workmen Die}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered]
     ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of posting a code fragment, it's much better to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `line width` parameter to the `edge` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={edge={->,line width=4pt}}
[{\textbf{Footbridge Dilemma}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
  [{\textbf{Push \\Man}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
     [{\textbf{Man \\Dies}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
       [{\textbf{Workmen \\Saved}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered]
     ]
  ]
  [{\textbf{Don't Push}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
     [{\textbf{Man \\Lives}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered
       [{\textbf{Workmen Die}}, circle, draw, text width = 5em, text centered]
     ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. It's always the little things.

Comment: Should be tagged `trolleyology` ... ;).